# Clicking on an element that's shown on hover

Tags: jquery, html, css

Let's assume I have a div with 2 children:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="sibling"></div>
</div>
```

Assume that when I hover on the 'child', its sibling is shown. 
Also assume that when I click the 'sibling', an alert appears.

However when my mouse is over the sibling, it begins to toggle on and off making clicking it almost impossible as you can see.

He's a fiddle reproducing the 'issue':
https://jsfiddle.net/7febqymt/

What would be the best approach to prevent the sibling from flickering, thus making clicks easily possible?

Comment: Are you specific with that HTML structure?? Can you consider placing the sibling div inside child div ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need JS for the hover/toggle effect.  Just add this line to your CSS and that will do the hover effect and fix the flickering:

```
.child:hover + .sibling, .sibling:hover {display:block;}
```

see updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7febqymt/1/

Comment: very clever use of the CSS + sign (adjacent sibling selector...)  Also this solution doesn't need JS to function.

Comment: wow this is really clever. but what if I had multiple siblings?

Comment: do you?  If so, you have to know what you want to happen in that case... is every sibling shown; is just the first one shown, etc?  it's all possible, though.

Comment: @andi sorry for not mentioning; yes, the exact same situation but with multiple siblings with the addition - all of them should be displayed if either of them gets hovered. I will probably need to extend the implementation later with multiple siblings, hence my additional question: https://jsfiddle.net/7febqymt/3/

Comment: you can use `.child:hover ~ .sibling` (all following siblings, not just adjacent).  However CSS can't select preceding siblings, so if you are hovering on sibling3, sibling1 and sibling2 will be hidden.  You might have to play around with the HTML structure if you need that to be different.

Answer (score 1):

Put 'sibling' inside 'child':

```html
<div class="parent">
  parent
  <div class="child">
    hover me
    <div class="sibling">
    click me
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/):

> ```
> $('.sibling').show();
> ```

<kbd>[**PLUNKER**](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/shz5g4zo/1/)</kbd>